# Arduino Multi tap function confusion

Tags: arrays, arduino, numeric-keypad

Im still very new to the c++ programming world so take it easy on me guys. haha

I trying to make a system to keep track of high scores for one of my dad's favorite games. I'm using a LCD screen and a 3x4 keypad for score entries. I would like to add a multi tap function to the keypad so it would act as if it was a phone keypad for storing the users initials. I have created a function for storing the score (it may not be the best way to do it but it works, comments on how to improve would be greatly appreciated.) I not even sure where to start on this one. I have looked at the dynamic keypad example in the Arduino keypad library but I feel I may have bitten of more than I can chew
my code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Keypad.h"

// Create a software serial port!
SoftwareSerial lcd = SoftwareSerial(11,10); 
char scoreinput[] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
int counter = -2;
int counter2=0;
uint8_t red, green, blue;



const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3'},
{'4','5','6'},
{'7','8','9'},
{'*','0','#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 6, 7, 8}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {2, 3, 4}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );


void setup() {
lcd.begin(9600); 
Serial.begin(9600);

lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
delay(10);
lcd.print("****PinScore*******************");
lcd.write(0xFE);//set cursor at home
lcd.write(0x48);
delay(5000);



lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
delay(10);
lcd.print("New High Score?");
lcd.write(0xFE);
lcd.write(0x47);
lcd.write((uint8_t)2);
lcd.print(" Press      \"#\"");
delay(5000);

lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
delay(10);
lcd.print("Display Scores?");
lcd.write(0xFE);
lcd.write(0x47);
lcd.write((uint8_t)2);
lcd.print(" Press      \"*\"");
delay(5000);

lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
lcd.print("     Press     ");
lcd.write(0xFE);
lcd.write(0x47);
lcd.write((uint8_t)2);
lcd.print(" \"*\"   or  \"#\" ");
}


void loop() {



char key = keypad.getKey();

if (key != NO_KEY){
Serial.print(key);
lcd.print(key);
counter++;
counter2++;
scoreinput[counter]=(key);
}

switch (key == '#'){
   case 1:




lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
delay(10);
lcd.print("Enter Your New  High Score");
delay(3000);
lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
lcd.print("Press \"#\" At Any Time To Reset");
delay(3000);
lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
lcd.print("Enter High Score:");


lcd.write(0xFE);
lcd.write(0x47);
lcd.write((uint8_t)18);
lcd.print(key);

if (counter==8){
  break;
}
}

if (counter==8){
lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
delay(1000);
lcd.print(scoreinput[0]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[1]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[2]);
lcd.print(",");
lcd.print(scoreinput[3]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[4]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[5]);
lcd.print(",");
lcd.print(scoreinput[6]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[7]);
lcd.print(scoreinput[8]);
counter=-2;
delay(3000);
lcd.write(0xFE); //clear display 
lcd.write(0x58);
lcd.print("Enter your      Initals:");
  }
while (counter2>10){
if (key == '2'){
//this is where the multi tap function would be called to allow users to enter their intials 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a timer to measure the time since the last key entry. If it has been greater than some amount of time (perhaps 1 second) since the last keystroke OR if the key is different than the last key pushed then enter a *new* character (the first character for the key; 2=A, 3=D, etc.) otherwise it increments the character (with wrap-around, A=>B, B=>C, C=>A). So "234" enters "ADG" and "222" enters "C" but "2(delay)22" enters "AB".